# PL/SQL ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to put this piece of code to a stored procedure. But the `Update` statement is throwing invalid datatype error. Any help or advice would be highly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE "TABLE1" 
(   
    "USER_ID" NUMBER, 
    "COMMENTS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
)

PROCEDURE pr_test
AS
    v_table UserRecordTable;
    v_user_id_list SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST;
BEGIN
    select USER_ID bulk collect into v_table 
    from TABLE1;

    select USER_ID bulk collect into v_user_id_list 
    from TABLE1 
    where USER_ID in (select USERID FROM TABLE(v_table)); -- No problem

FOR i IN 1..v_user_id_list.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Column1: ' || v_user_id_list(i)); -- printout ok
END LOOP;

UPDATE TABLE1    -- This line throws the error
SET COMMENTS= 'NO NO'
where USER_ID in (select USERID FROM TABLE(v_table));
END pr_der_test;
```

In Spec

```
   TYPE UserRecordType IS RECORD (
    USERID TABLE1.USER_ID%TYPE
  ); 
TYPE UserRecordTable IS TABLE OF UserRecordType;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PL/SQL ORA-00902: invalid datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77395892/pl-sql-ora-00902-invalid-datatype)

Comment: Please show the definition of `v_table`, `v_user_id_list` and `table1`.  You provided the spec for `UserRecordTable ` but that appears nowhere in the code you've shared.

Comment: @Paul I have updated the sample code. Please have a look.  And USERID is Number type in table1.

Comment: @KoenLostrie wrong link?

Comment: @Rich, what about `PriorityRecordTable` and the DDL for `TABLE1` ? We still don't know anything about these.

Comment: @PaulW That was a typo. it should be UserRecordTable. And TABLE1 has USER_ID  which is Number type. I made some simplification for this sample case because I only use this one field for this user case.

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LK6Ij_H4) demonstrating the error. @Rich - you should include a complete [MRE] in your question that we can just copy-paste and execute. If we have to try to reverse engineer your setup from the question then it increases the burden on the answerers and makes it less likely that you are going to get assistance. Help us to help you and provide us with everything we need in an usable format.

Comment: @MT0 I have updated the question with full example. And I have tested this simplified code which can be used for reproducing the error.

Comment: @rich I flagged it as dupe because you created 2 - the other one is now deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably relates to records being a PL/SQL data-type and that their support is limited in SQL statements (but increasing in more recent versions).

You can work around the problem using `v_user_id_list` in the query (which uses `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST`, a data-type declared in the SQL scope and not in a PL/SQL scope of a package).

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE package_name
AS 
  TYPE UserRecordType IS RECORD (USERID TABLE1.USER_ID%TYPE); 
  TYPE UserRecordTable IS TABLE OF UserRecordType;
  PROCEDURE pr_test;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY package_name
AS 
  PROCEDURE pr_test
  AS
    v_table UserRecordTable;
    v_user_id_list SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST;
  BEGIN
    select USER_ID
    bulk collect into v_table 
    from  TABLE1;

    select USER_ID
    bulk collect into v_user_id_list 
    from TABLE1 
    where USER_ID in (select USERID FROM TABLE(v_table)); -- No problem

    FOR i IN 1..v_user_id_list.COUNT LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Column1: ' || v_user_id_list(i)); -- printout ok
    END LOOP;

    UPDATE TABLE1    -- This line throws the error
    SET COMMENTS= 'NO NO'
    -- where USER_ID in (select USERID FROM TABLE(v_table))
    where USER_ID in (select COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_user_id_list))
    ;
  END;
END;
/
```

Given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1(
  user_id  NUMBER,
  comments VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO table1 (user_id, comments)
SELECT 1, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'YES' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();
  package_name.pr_test;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```sql
> Column1: 1
> Column1: 2
> ```

And the table then contains:

| USER_ID | COMMENTS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NO NO |
| 2 | NO NO |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2TS5yLEI)

Comment: @MTO Thanks so much. This works. But if I need other columns, the list is not enough. That was why I tried to user Table of Record. And one more question, I was wondering why would this works with the same where clause? 

select USER_ID
    bulk collect into v_user_id_list 
    from TABLE1 
    where USER_ID in (select USERID FROM TABLE(v_table));

Comment: @Rich As I said in the answer, support for PL/SQL data-types is limited in the SQL scope. It may be that record types are supported in `SELECT` statements but have either limited or no support in `UPDATE` statements. I don't have a good reference for what support is available where and it would also depend on which version of the database you are using.

Comment: If you want to use multi-column data-types then declare an `OBJECT` data-type in the SQL scope and that should be supported in both the PL/SQL and SQL scopes.

Comment: @MTO Much appreciated! I will accept this answer and give it a try with OBJECT data-type.